# XSS Atack for Microsoft Report Viewer in c#

Tags: .net, reportviewer

I using .net Framework with microsft report viewer, I wanna prevent xss atacks on Report Viewer Reserved Url. How to prevent it? Runtime version: v2.0.50727 Report Viewer version: 8.0.0.0